# What type of stormtrooper is this one wearing a cape?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens, character-identification

In this image taken from the Databank page for [Tuanul](https://www.starwars.com/databank/tuanul) we can see a stormtrooper with a cape in the background.

[image: Tuanul, caped stormtrooper]

Do we know what type of stormtrooper this is?

---

It would not appear to be a snowtrooper as their long coats are generally form fitting and quite tight.

[image: Snowtroopers]

The Star Wars wikia also identifies a caped stormtrooper type as ["Wet-weather gear stormtrooper"](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Wet-weather_gear_stormtrooper) but these are from the Imperial era and first showed up in *Solo: A Star Wars Story*.

[image: Wet-weather gear stormtrooper]

Comment: On a side note the wet-weather gear stormtrooper at the front of the image has his wrong knee on the floor like a proper muppet.

Comment: ***No capes!***

Comment: I can't see this caped avenger in the actual film...

Comment: I'm not convinced that's part of that Stormtrooper's uniform. The color has a bluish tint to it that doesn't match the white of the armor. I'm inclined to believe that's an object or one of the people of the settlement draped in a cloth, and that the Stormtrooper is simply standing behind it/them.

Comment: @Valorum I couldn't either when I watched the Tuanul scene back.

Comment: @vynsane Possible but the blueish tint appears to be caused by a shadow (see the top part of the cape) and the cape does seem to follow the stormtroopers body and be attached to it.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot Given the physical requirements necessary for a stable firing stance without a twisted body, I'd say the real muppet was the costume designer who put the knee pad on the wrong leg...

Comment: Maybe that's captain Phasma, doesn't she have a cape somewhere, she wears sometimes?  She can apparently wear whatever she feels like.

Comment: @MarkRogers Was discussed in a now deleted answer, doesn't appear to be her. She has a black cape which generally falls over her left shoulder. The stormtrooper in the image also very clearly looks to be wearing white rather than chrome. And "looking closer, the faceplate style is wrong, too".

Comment: Caped Stormtroopers have superpowers (reads: force sensitivity).

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot - That's a standard shooting kneeling position. Lead leg up supports the barrel hand.

Comment: @JohnP I know, the plate on the left knee is meant to be a support for kneeling though.

Comment: Now can't unsee: thats not a cape, he's wearing a towel around his waist!

Comment: @JamieClinton Oh! Damn you!

Comment: @JamieClinton It's not a towel, it's a skirt.

Comment: I'm surprised that no one has made [this reference](http://www.bluemilkspecial.com/comic/tk-8008-strikes-back/) yet...

Answer (score 43, accepted):

That's not a cape on the stormtrooper, that's someone closer to the camera.

Note that the "cape" is not as out of focus as the trooper, indicating a different distance from the camera. And if you look, there's a distinct difference in colour: the light blue terminates abruptly against the white of the armour. Further, there are two projections out at either side.

What you are looking at is someone wearing a light blue cloak over a grayish-brown top who is kneeling and slightly bent over. They have their arms raised and bent, just as the other prisoners in the scene do, but because they're bent over their forearms are more parallel to the ground (and thus not as obvious from that angle).

Here is a zoomed in view:

[image]

Note the trooper on the left: blaster in their right hand, and their left hand obviously on the shoulder of the kneeling person.

Answer (score 13):

This (00:06:22) appears to be the same scene viewed from a slightly different angle, possibly a second take(?). In it we see a First Order stormtrooper ***throwing a villager to the ground in front of him.*** The villager is wearing a voluminous grey/blue jacket (or possibly a blue dress) that billows slightly.

Since we don't see any other cape-wearing stormtroopers exiting the shuttles, my instinct is that ***this isn't a cape but just something that was in front of the trooper at the moment the picture was taken.***

[image]

Comment: I believe is it probably a kneeling villager in the original picture.

Comment: @ThePopMachine - Kneeling or being manhandled